# Backup on a remote server in an encrypted folder

Tags: backup, encryption

Is there an easy way to backup your home directory on an online server in an encrypted folder?

I heard of [`obnam`](http://obnam.org/) which should be able to store encrypted with a GPG key somehow.

What would be the commands I need to configure a backup of my folder `~/` (on Ubuntu 14.10) to our online Debian server so no other root admin can read my personal backup?

Comment: Is that a current backup or a set of incremental backups? Should the backup be mountable or should it consist of archive files?

Comment: A mountable, incremental backup would be perfect. Like rsnapshot but encrypted

Answer (score 1):

`encfs` has a `--reverse` option. 
Essentially, you get an encrypted view of your home folder at the mountpoint and then you can rsync the encrypted view.

> ```
> --reverse
> ```
>
> Normally EncFS provides a plaintext view of data on demand.  Normally it stores enciphered data and
>   displays plaintext data.  With `--reverse` it takes as source plaintext data and produces enciphered
>   data on-demand.  This can be useful for creating remote encrypted backups, where you do not wish to
>   keep the local files unencrypted.
>
> For example, the following would create an encrypted view in `/tmp/crypt-view`.
>
> ```
> encfs --reverse /home/me /tmp/crypt-view
> ```
>
> You could then copy the `/tmp/crypt-view` directory in order to have a copy of the encrypted data.
>   You must also keep a copy of the file `/home/me/.encfs5` which contains the filesystem information.
>   Together, the two can be used to reproduce the unencrypted data:
>
> ```
> ENCFS5_CONFIG=/home/me/.encfs5 encfs /tmp/crypt-view /tmp/plain-view
> ```
>
> Now `/tmp/plain-view` contains the same data as `/home/me`
>
> Note that `--reverse` mode only works with limited configuration options, so many settings may be disabled when used.